# How could I display parent object attribute in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

### At the moment I'm working on an e-commerce application.

It contains a sub-app called "blog".
The idea is that the superuser creates an account for the **Trainer*.
[And yeah, I already created a new AbstractUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfF4c.jpg)

Trainer logins into his account and creates Post
[I logged in here using my Trainer`s credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVrU0.jpg)

After I want the superuser to see WHO created post, but DjangoAdmin displays me admin`s email

How could I display the email of the 'creator' of the post in Django admin?

Code:

```
#models.py
class UserTrainer(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=100, unique=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    info = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/stuff_images')
    inst = models.URLField(blank=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_email(self):
        return self.object.email


class Post(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_TRAINER_ID = 1

    article = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Article text')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(UserTrainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

#admin.py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = UserTrainer
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        *UserAdmin.fieldsets,
        (
            'TrainerInfo',
            {
                'fields': (
                    'age', 'info', 'image', 'inst',
                )
            }
        )
    )

admin.site.register(UserTrainer, CustomUserAdmin)
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('article', 'slug','trainer')
    list_display_links = ('article',)
    fields = ('article', 'slug', 'keywords', 'text',)
    readonly_fields = ('trainer',)
```

Comment: Have you tried to put list_display = list_display = ('article', 'slug','trainer__email') ?

Comment: It doesn't work,here is what i get :
"The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'trainer__email', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog. Post'."

Comment: You write _...DjangoAdmin displays me admins email_ but are you sure that this is not the email set of the specific `UserTrainer` which is linked as trainer in `Post`? I think Django will not display another email address than set in the DB.

Comment: @Marco No, because I log out from the admin account, And create Post as Trainer
(I log in to Trainer`s account that was created by admin)
I have suspicions about the Foreign Key default attribute

Comment: Why do you use a default for `trainer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are are not specifying user when you save your post, so you should override your save method in admin.py, try this ([OFFICIAL DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)):

```
admin.site.register(UserTrainer, CustomUserAdmin)
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('article', 'slug','trainer')
    list_display_links = ('article',)
    fields = ('article', 'slug', 'keywords', 'text',)
    readonly_fields = ('trainer',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.trainer = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: That works,
thank you so much 
really spent a lot of hours dealing with this problem
thank you once again!